# Validation about chosen graph showing rates with big gap between them

Tags: multiple-comparisons, method-comparison

I'm trying to show the variation in time of 4 variables, in which the first one is in the order of 20-30 and the remainder are all smaller than 2.
The growth rates for each are: 52, 70, 8.85 and 19.06.
However in the chart that I attached, it is not possible to see that variation and it seems that the first variable is the one that has had the greatest variation.

Am I choosing the wrong graphic? You should modify the variables in some way to only show the last 3 and discard the first one.

```
dat1 <- data.frame( category = factor(c("Category1","Category1","Category2","Category2","Category3","Category3","Category4","Category4")), 
                    year = factor(c("1981","2014","1981","2014","1981","2014","1981","2014"), 
                                  levels=c("1975","2000")), 
                    total_value = c(22.30, 33.94, 0.625842, 1.061414, 
                                    0.056670, 0.061684, 0.009899, 0.011785) )


us1mat <- matrix( dat1$total_value,
                  nrow = 4,
                  byrow=TRUE,
                  dimnames = list(c("Category1","Category2", "Category3", "Category4"), c("1975", "2000"))
)

usfm_col <- c("blue", "black", "Red", "Green")

matplot(t(us1mat), type="b", lty=1, pch=19, col=usfm_col,
        cex=1.5, lwd=3, las=1, bty="n", xaxt="n",
        xlim=c(0.7, 2.2), ylim=c(0,35), ylab="",
        main="Rates per 1,000 person-year", yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=axTicks(2), labels=axTicks(2),
     las=1, cex.axis=0.8, col=NA, line = -0.5)
grid(NA, NULL, lty=3, lwd=1, col="#000000")
abline(v=c(1,2), lty=3, lwd=1, col="#000000")
mtext("1975", side=1, at=1)
mtext("2000", side=1, at=2)
```

[image: Graph showing 4 variables with their variation over time]

Comment: Logarithmic scale?

Comment: @Nick Cox Firstly, thank for your answer. I didn't have any idea about logarithmic scale. I have already found a lot of information and I will be working on that in order to correct my previous visualization. http://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/19/when-should-i-use-logarithmic-scales-in-my-charts-and-graphs/#4a2c861b3cd8